# Limit the number of pods per node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I'm trying to limit the number of pods per each node from my cluster.
I managed to add a global limit per node from kubeadm init with config file:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
networking:
  podSubnet: <subnet>
---
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
maxPods: 10
```

This is not quite well because the limit is applied even on master node (where multiple kube-system pods are running and the number of pods here may increase over 10).
I would like to keep the default value at init and change the value at join on each node.
I have found something:

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
maxPods: 10
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: JoinConfiguration
discovery:
  bootstrapToken:
    apiServerEndpoint: "<api_endpoint>"
    token: "<token>"
    unsafeSkipCAVerification: true
```

but, even if no error/warning appears, it seems that the value of maxPods is ignored. I can create more than 10 pods for that specific node.
Also `kubectl get node <node> -o yaml` `returns status.capacity.pods` with its default value (110).
How can I proceed in order to have this pods limit applied per each node?

I would like to mention that I have basic/limited knowledge related to Kubernetes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a config.yaml file at `/var/lib/kubelet`. This config file is generated from kubelet config map in kube-system namespace when you run kubeadm join.Partial content of the file is as below.

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
clusterDNS:
- 10.96.0.10
maxPods: 10
```

You can change that file and add maxPods parameter and then restart kubelet on the node.

```
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Currently in kubeadm join there is no way to pass a kubelet config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the maximum number of pods per node with the kubelet `--max-pods` option.