# Can we increase number of pods per node in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubelet, bare-metal-server

I've deployed Kubernetes cluster on my local machine.The default allocatable pods in Kubernetes are 110. I want to increase the number of pods per node in my cluster.Can anyone let me know if it's possible ? If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit the number of pods per node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378117/limit-the-number-of-pods-per-node)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can control this with the `max-pods` option to the Kubelet, either via a command line flag or Kubelet config file option. But beware that we don't test as much outside the normal scaling targets so you might be able to break things.

Comment: Can I change the max-pod value using command line flag after the creation of cluster

Comment: Sure, you just need to change the CLI options passed to Kubelet on startup.